# Does my fine-tuned model differ from the original model (BERT model)

Tags: nlp, bert-language-model

The question sounds silly at first, so I'll elaborate:

I'm finetuning this model

```
ConvBertModel.from_pretrained("sarnikowski/convbert-medium-small-da-cased")
```

on a multilabel sentiment classification task. After having trained the model on my data, I load my fine-tuned model like this:

```
#Loading the best version (according to the validation loss) of the model:
trained_model = Tagger.load_from_checkpoint(
  trainer.checkpoint_callback.best_model_path,
  n_classes=3
)
trained_model.eval()
trained_model.freeze()
```

This `trained_model` should according to my understanding be equal to the architecture of the model before fine-tuning it (of course the weights have changed). But still I'm getting errors whenever I try to use my trained_model for other tasks. One of these tasks are getting the SHAP values for the predictions using the [transformers-interpret](https://github.com/cdpierse/transformers-interpret#multilabel-classification-explainer) library:

```
from transformers_interpret import MultiLabelClassificationExplainer

model = trained_model # my fine-tuned model
tokenizer = ConvBertTokenizer.from_pretrained("sarnikowski/convbert-medium-small-da-cased")


cls_explainer = MultiLabelClassificationExplainer(model, tokenizer)


word_attributions = cls_explainer("There were many aspects of the film I liked, but it was frightening and gross in parts. My parents hated it.")
```

Outputs the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-0000c765e477> in <module>
      2 cls_explainer = MultiLabelClassificationExplainer(
      3     trained_model,
----> 4     tokenizer
      5     )
      6 

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers_interpret/explainers/multilabel_classification.py in __init__(self, model, tokenizer, attribution_type, custom_labels)
     35         custom_labels: Optional[List[str]] = None,
     36     ):
---> 37         super().__init__(model, tokenizer, attribution_type, custom_labels)
     38         self.labels = []
     39 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers_interpret/explainers/sequence_classification.py in __init__(self, model, tokenizer, attribution_type, custom_labels)
     51             AttributionTypeNotSupportedError:
     52         """
---> 53         super().__init__(model, tokenizer)
     54         if attribution_type not in SUPPORTED_ATTRIBUTION_TYPES:
     55             raise AttributionTypeNotSupportedError(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/transformers_interpret/explainer.py in __init__(self, model, tokenizer)
     17         self.tokenizer = tokenizer
     18 
---> 19         if self.model.config.model_type == "gpt2":
     20             self.ref_token_id = self.tokenizer.eos_token_id
     21         else:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   1206                 return modules[name]
   1207         raise AttributeError("'{}' object has no attribute '{}'".format(
-> 1208             type(self).__name__, name))
   1209 
   1210     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value: Union[Tensor, 'Module']) -> None:

AttributeError: 'Tagger' object has no attribute 'config'
```

Here is a link to the whole notebook: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dH-rkZKslnBoRFvpsVvt9fj67NgMfLP0?usp=sharing

**Am I wrong in thinking that the fine-tuned model do not behave in the same way as the original model?**

Comment: what is Tagger here? did you import it, define it in your code, etc?